# change web browser URL property?

Tags: string, visual-studio-2013, webbrowser-control

[image]How to assign a string array value to visual studios web browser URL property?
i have made a string array,and i want to assign that array values to the VS web browsers URL property,so can you please help me to resolve this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this format of string to set the URI:

```
"http://www.domain.com/"
```

Comment: Thankyou so much bro,problem solved :) it really helped me.